# Prolog - 2 ways for progenitor predicate implementation

Tags: prolog, parent-child, failure-slice, transitive-closure

Given a set of facts that represent parent-child relationships via the predicate **parent/2**, what are the differences when defining the relation "progenitor"(ancestor) with the predicates **pred1/2** and **pred2/2** as shown below?

```
pred1(X,Z) :- parent(X,Z).
pred1(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y), pred1(Y,Z).

pred2(X,Z) :- parent(X,Z).
pred2(X,Z) :- parent(Y,Z), pred2(X,Y).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major difference are the termination properties of both, provided there are some cycles in the relation. To understand this, I will use a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) which cuts down the program to its essence w.r.t. termination.

```
pred1(X,Z) :- false, parent(X,Z).
pred1(X,Z) :- parent(X,Y), pred1(Y,Z). % Z has no influence

pred2(X,Z) :- false, parent(X,Z).
pred2(X,Z) :- parent(Y,Z), pred2(X,Y). % X has no influence
```

For `pred1/2`, the second argument has no influence on termination at all, whereas in `pred2/2`, the first argument has no influence. To see this, try the original definitions with the fact:

```
parent(a,a).

?- pred1(b, _), false.
   false. % terminates
?- pred2(b, _), false.
   loops.
?- pred1(_, b), false.
   loops.
?- pred2(_, b), false.
   false. % terminates
```

See [`closure/3`](/q/26946133) for a general approach to avoid such loops.

For completeness, here is another variation of transitive closure which has some conceptual advantages:

```
pred3(X,Z) :- parent(X,Z).
pred3(X,Z) :- pred3(X,Y), pred3(Y,Z).
```

Alas, its termination properties are worst. In fact, it *never* terminates, as is testified by the following fragment:

```
pred3(X,Z) :- false, parent(X,Z).
pred3(X,Z) :- pred3(X,Y), false, pred3(Y,Z).
```

In this fragment, the first argument is only passed on. So, no matter, what the arguments are, the program will always loop!

```
?- pred3(b,b), false.
   loops.
```